# Создание таблицы sqlite3 в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
orders_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  "user_orders" (
    "date"  TEXT,
    "warehouseName" TEXT,
    "oblast"    TEXT,
    "nmId"  INTEGER,
    "subject"   TEXT,
    "isCancel"  TEXT
);"""
```

не могу понять почему у меня нет типа данных `TEXT`, когда создаю таблицу. Его даже нет в выпадающем списке, что я делаю не так? работаю через `PyCharm`

```
orders_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders_data (ord_date DATE , wh TEXT , obl TEXT , nmId INT , sub TEXT, canc TEXT)"""
```

Comment: Кто же знает где и почему у Вас чего-то нет?

Comment: Ну да, согласен) вроде бы sqlite3 стандартная библиотека, а не содержит в себе TEXT даже странно. Есть только MESSAGE_TEXT

Comment: TEXT - один из стандартных типов SQLite. A кто и где у **Вас** не содержит TEXT - не известно. Перечитайте свой текст. Почитайте [ask] [mre] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question